# Blender cannot recognize CUDA graphics card for headless render on linux

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, gpu

I'm trying to do headless cycle rendering on a linux server with nvidia gpu. Blender seems to have trouble finding the gpu.

Running nvidia-smi gives me:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.78       Driver Version: 410.78       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  TITAN Xp            On   | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   24C    P8    15W / 250W |      0MiB / 12196MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

which shows that I've got a supported card with compatible driver version.

But running blender (2.80-a3b88c917299)

```
blender --enable-autoexec --python "path/to/test_script.py" --background -noaudio
```

with this script

```
# test_script.py
import bpy

bpy.context.scene.cycles.device = 'GPU'
cprefs = bpy.context.preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences

print(bpy.context.scene.cycles.device)
print(cprefs.compute_device_type)
print(len(cprefs.devices))
```

gives me

```
GPU
CUDA
0
```

So blender does found CUDA but found 0 CUDA devices. But nvidia-smi show that I do have a compatible device. What could be the reason? Do I need to refresh or update in some way to let blender recognize the gpu?